# Does the range-based for loop cache the container expression, or re-evaluate it each iteration?

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach

I have the following code:

```
for (auto it = _locations.locations().begin(); it != _locations.locations().end(); ++it)
   // Do something
```

I wanted to replace it with

```
for (const auto& location: _locations.locations())
   // Do something
```

but then realized I don't know how it's going to work. Will the `locations()` method be called each iteration, or will the result of the container expression evaluation be "cached" locally, resulting in only one `locations()` call? Does the standard define this behavior one way or the other?

Comment: Did you consult the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I did consult with that very article. Didn't see it explicitly stated anywhere, although now I notice the `auto && __range = range_expression ;` line in the "Explanation" pseudocode.

Comment: Note that the code in @NathanOliver link is actually how it is specified in the standard, with notes that variable names are just for explanations sake.  That isn't "Explanation pseudocode" as much as "a quote from the standard".  Some of the clauses have results described by the standard, but a for-each loop in C++11 behaves as specified *by that code block*.

Comment: It also has *If range_expression returns a temporary, its lifetime is extended until the end of the loop, as indicated by binding to the rvalue reference __range, but beware that the lifetime of any temporary within range_expression is not extended.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's required to be "cached".

§[stmt.ranged]/1 says:

> In each case, a range-based for statement is equivalent to

```
{
    auto && __range = range-init;
    for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
               __end = end-expr;
               __begin != __end;
               ++__begin ) {
                   for-range-declaration = *__begin;
                   statement
              } 
}
```

So this requires that the `begin-expr` and `end-expr` each be invoked only once (though, of course, that's subject to the normal "as-if" rule, so this is subject to change if, for example, they have no observable side effects).

Comment: ... with the `__` variables being merely exposition, and the result of the expressions being described elsewhere.  In theory, `begin-expr` and `end-expr` could evaluate to objects that reinvoke `.end()` and `.begin()` on each `!=` comparison, for example.  (this is not the case unless you jump through some extreme hoops)

Comment: @Yakk: I don't even know how to achieve that. Thoughts?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe return iterators that wrap container that call `begin`/`end` each time.  This is not a good idea: iterating over a container that mutates while you iterate will usually **not work reliably**, and when it fails it will fail in ways that are difficult to predict.  Don't mutate containers as you iterate over them.